# Expo Publish fails with ERROR read ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have been trying to publish an expo managed app with the expo publish command but the process fails every time with an error ECONNRESET.
The JavaScript bundle builds correctly and the error happens right after.
The app works well in development and in production mode too. I have also sentry-expo added to my project.
My expo-cli version is 3.11.3. I am running windows 10 Home, Version 1903, OS build 18362.657

Error:

```
Building iOS bundle
Building JavaScript bundle [====                                                                                                ] 4%
>
Building Android bundle
Building JavaScript bundle [====================================================================================================] 100%Finished building JavaScript bundle in 37492ms.
Analyzing assets
Building JavaScript bundle [====================================================================================================] 100%Finished building JavaScript bundle in 24311ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 8076ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 8432ms.
Uploading assets
No assets changed, skipped.
Processing asset bundle patterns:
- C:\Users\User\Desktop\React Native\scripts\smartpass-app\**\*
Building sourcemaps
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 14796ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 1080ms.
Uploading JavaScript bundles
read ECONNRESET
(node:7328) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
raven@2.6.3 alert: failed to send exception to sentry: Socket timed out on request to sentry.io
raven@2.6.3 alert: failed to send exception to sentry: socket hang up
```

>

[image]

Comment: It seems like the server is closing the connection before completion.  Is this async function ?

Comment: It minifies and uploads the project code to their servers makes the app available through a URL. The internals of how it works are not documented in their website

Answer (score 1):

It seems the antivirus and firewall had been the issue. The publish and build went well after I disabled my antivirus and firewall temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

solution: goto firewall & network protection, and click on "restore firewalls to default

then run expo publish, you will prompt with node trying to connect just click allow

thats it

Comment: Can you please provide sources or more detailed steps that can be verified?

Comment: You can do either of truning off fire wall or restore fire fall defaults 
just type in windows menu search "firewall and network protection"
then click on "restore firewwalls to default"
that's it